# How to hide js libraries used in my Django app

Tags: javascript, django, websecurity

I have been researching on web security and discovered that it is possible to detect the js libraries used on your site and allow a hacker to use that information to use a specific attack. I can't find any way of hiding that information in my Django app when using penetrating testing tools

Answer (score 1):

DJango is based on python, not javascript. Unless you are using some curious js-in-python on the backend, there shouldn't really be any serious security problems related to js

Most likely, your js is entirely client-side... in which case, webpack or gulp can bundle all your javascript so that a client cannot immediately know the name of the packages you are using. Note, however, a client will still get all the code -- sufficient analysis of the bundle will probably be able to reproduce the list of packages you use